# Problem fbjs with special characters

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs

An error occurred when we have special characters

```
 <input value="Search Today's Deals" onfocus="if(this.getValue() == 'Search Today's Deals'){this.setValue('')}" />
```

When I click this textbox it show issue:

```
Failed to processs FBML JavaScript. Exception = "Javascript parse error, unexpected: RCURLY"
```

Please help me a way solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the single quotes within single quotes need escaping:
try this code :

```
 <input value="Search Today's Deals" onfocus="if(this.getValue() == 'Search Today\'s Deals'){this.setValue('')}" />
```